# Skip ECSOperator Task in airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I wanted to skip ECSOperator Task in airflow.
Basically I have two tasks:

```
CUSTOMER_CONFIGS = [
    {
        'customer_name': 'test',
        'start_date': 17  # day of the month on which you want to trigger task
    },
    {
        'customer_name': 'test',
        'start_date': 18  # day of the month on which you want to trigger task
    }
]

default_args = {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 0
}

with DAG(
        dag_id='run-ecs-task',
        default_args=default_args,
        start_date=days_ago(1),
        schedule_interval='0 0 * * *',
        max_active_runs=1,

) as dag:
    current_day = datetime.now()
    current_day = current_day.strftime("%d")
    tasks = []
    for config in CUSTOMER_CONFIGS:
        task = ECSOperator(
            task_id=f'{config.get("customer_name")}',
            dag=dag,
            retries=AIRFLOW_ECS_OPERATOR_RETRIES,
            retry_delay=timedelta(seconds=10),
            **ecs_operator_args
        )
        if config.get('start_date') != current_day:
            task.state = State.SKIPPED
        tasks.append(task)
```

How can I skip first ecs task on the bases of some condition.

Latern I would like to make these tasks in sequece

Comment: I tried to create custom Operator and then try to raise AirflowSkipException but it does not worked as expected.

Comment: Basicaly i have defined a day of the month on which a specific task will run. For example some tasks are not supposed to run today then they will be skipped

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what is the condition but in general you can use `ShortCircuitOperator`. The ShortCircuitOperator is derived from the PythonOperator. It evaluates a condition and short-circuits the workflow if the condition is False.

```
from airflow.operators.python import ShortCircuitOperator

def condition():
    if 1 > 2: # Replace with your condition
        return True
    return False

conditional_task = ShortCircuitOperator(
    task_id='condition',
    python_callable=func
)

task = ECSOperator(...)
task2 = ECSOperator(...)


conditional_task >> task
task2
```

Comment: Have updated question.

Comment: @ALTAFHUSSAIN I don't fully understand the logic of your code. the answer is the same use ShortCircuitOperator before the your first operator.